# Django: how do you filter with dates and a foreign key

Tags: python, django, date

Inside of models I have:

1. The Hotel Name
2. The price for each night.

## models.py:

```
class Hotel_Database(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Hotel_Date_Price(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel_Database, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='hotel')
    checkin = models.DateField(default= datetime.date.today())  
    checkout = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(1))   
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

## views.py:

```
import datetime
x = Hotel_Database.objects.get(id=1)
#the price for the night of June 26th:
Hotel_Date_Price.objects.create(hotel = x, checkin= datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), checkout=datetime.date(2018, 6,28), price=50).save()
#the price for the night of June 27th:
Hotel_Date_Price.objects.create(hotel = x, checkin= datetime.date(2018, 6, 28), checkout=datetime.date(2018, 6,29), price=50).save()


Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel', hotel__checkin__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 28))
#results: <QuerySet [<Hotel_Database: Shangri-La>]>
```

Now here is what happens when I try to filter through more than one night:

```
Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel', hotel__checkin__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 29))
#results: <QuerySet []> 
# it returns an empty list
```

I am basically trying to change the price of each night

Comment: ... but the checkout is not greater than the 29th, it is the 28th which is less.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you confused `lte` and `gte`. `lte` means less than, while `gte` is greater than. So you should use end date with `lte` condition and start date with `gte`:

```
Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel', hotel__checkin__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 29))
```

Also note you don't need to call `save()` after `create()` method. You can just use `create()`.

**UPD**

If you need to exclude hotels with specific period of checkin/checkout from queryset you can use `exclude()`:

```
Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel').exclude( hotel__checkin__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 29))
```

Comment: The problem is that it returns the name of the hotel even when it is not available.  If I use the same example but I change the date: Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel', hotel__checkin__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 30)). It will still return both of the objects yes but it shouldn't return anything because there are no availability during those times. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Antoine ah, I suppose you need `exclude` in this case. `Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel').exclude( hotel__checkin__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 29))`

Comment: I understand your explanation. However what if I want to be able to filter through those dates? Hotel_Database.objects.filter(hotel_name__icontains='Hotel', hotel__checkin__gte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 27), hotel__checkout__lte=datetime.date(2018, 6, 30)). This is for a hotel booking website where the user enters the checkin and checkout dates. Based on the example the hotel room is not available during the night of the 29th. I might have to change my whole models I understand you don't have to give me a specific answer but if you can guide me down the right path. It'd be great.

Comment: @Antoine sorry I cannot understand what you trying to do. First query will give all hotels with checkin/checkout in range. Second will give all remaining hotels. Do you need something different?

Comment: Think about a hotel booking website! A user enters the destination, travel dates and the number of people. The next page will display the available hotels according to the travel dates. Makes more sense? (it's really hard to explain, that's for bearing with me :) )

Comment: @Antoine yes, now it's more clear, but I'm afraid you should rewrite your models:) Current models only contain dates, while you need rooms count also. So I would add at least `Room` model. And later rewrite query based on free rooms.